# Is there a way to test the significance between 2 linear mixed models in SAS?

Tags: sas

There is a baseline mean model and a model for only males/females subsets of the same data. There are 3 data points over time so the models are:
DV= age age*age age*age*age;
(Using Proc Mixed)
for the overall and for males and for females.
The trend lines are good, but I am having difficulty testing significance due to a difference in sample size.

In the mean trend, there is a -2LL of 6234.4 and a sample size of 2054.
In the male trend, there is a -2LL of 3116.2 and a sample size of 1043.

Am I right that the likelihood ratio test is 3118.2 with df of 1011? This was significant at alpha=0.05.

Is a likelihood ratio test even the correct approach?

Comment: This should probably go on Cross Validated & I don't follow exactly what you want to do; if you want to compare males vs. females then including sex as an interacting predictor seems most appropriate?

Comment: I did include sex as a predictor and it was significant, but we wanted to test if each cohort had a prediction model that was separately significantly different from the mean model which included both sexes. Maybe this is the same thing (including as predictor) and we dont need to test significance? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's indeed a different question, though you can still readily get that from a model with sex predictor(s): compare the means for the reference sex (predictor=0), for the other (predictor=1), and overall (predictor=whatever fraction of non-reference sex). I'm not so sure that makes too much sense however, because you already *know* that the sexes differ & the overall mean will depend to some extent on the observed/hypothesized (arbitrary?) fraction of each sex.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I think, based on a similar question in this site, is the anova that R can do between 2 models. I was able to determine that sex was a significant predictor, but how much of a deviation is considered clinically significant is what I am trying to figure out because there isnt a lot of literature to compare. I will keep trying! You have a good suggestion.